# I could not load the locations after selecting city?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a text fields with test name,city and location when I select the city it has to load the locations automatically and it has worked fine before.But,now it is showing the problem when I select the city it is not loading locations.Please help me.

form.phtml

```
      <?php
  /**
  * Catalog advanced search form
   *
   * @see Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form
  */
   ?>
  <?php

      $url=str_replace("/index.php","",Mage::getBaseUrl());
     $collection =          Mage::getModel("serviceprovider/serviceprovider")->getCollection();
      $collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);

        foreach($collection as $dta){
       $ct=strtolower($dta->getCity());
    $dta1[]=ucfirst($ct);

  }

     $dta1=array_unique($dta1);


 ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.labwise.in/js/autocomplete.jquery.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.labwise.in/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css/autocomplete.css" media="all" />
 <style>
 .autocomplete-jquery-results{
 margin-top: 38px;
   width: 107px;
  z-index: 9999;
 }
  </style>
  <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            /* Una vez que se cargo la pagina , llamo a todos los autocompletes y
             * los inicializo */
            jQuery('.autocomplete').autocomplete();
        });
      </script>


    <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>!-->
 <?php $maxQueryLength= $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getMaxQueryLength();?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<!---->
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getSearchPostUrl() ?>"  method="get" id="form-custom-search">
 <div class="form-search">
<label for="search"><?php echo $this->__("Search:");?></label>
       <!-- <div class="input-box testname">
            <input id="name"  class="input-text " type="text" maxlength="164" title="TestName" value="" name="name" placeholder="TestName">
        </div>!-->
        <div class="input-box testname autocomplete">
       <input  name="name"  maxlength="164" class="input-text " type="text"  id="name" value="" data-source="<?php echo $url;?>search.php?search=" placeholder="Enter Test Name  Lipid Profile, CBP,  FBS,  RBS  etc." />
    </div>
        <div   class="input-box city">
       <select id="city" class="input-text " name="city"  placeholder="City" onchange="autocompleteLocation(this.value)">
            <!--option  name="" value=""></option-->
            <option  name="city" value="0">City</option>

            <?php 

            foreach($dta1 as  $key=>$value) {?>

            <option  value="<?php echo $value;?>" ><?php echo $value;?></option>
            <?php

            }

            ?>
            <!--<option  name="city" value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
            <option name="city" value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
            <option name="city" value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
            <option name="city" value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
    <option name="city" value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
    <option name="city" value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>-->
       </select> 
     <!--  <input style="width:66px" id="city" class="input-text " type="text" maxlength="164" title="City" value="" name="city" placeholder="City"> -->
        </div> 
        <!-- comment the pincode for first release
        <div  class="input-box pincode">
             <input  id="pincode" class="input-text " type="text" maxlength="164" title="Pincode" value="" name="pincode" placeholder="Pin(optional)">
        </div> -->
        <div  class="input-box location" id="location_div">
             <!--input  id="location" class="input-text " type="text" maxlength="164" title="Location" value="" name="location" placeholder="Loc(optional)"-->
        <select id="location" class="input-text " name="location"  placeholder="Loc(optional)" >
            <option  name="Location" value=""></option>
            <!--<option  name="location" value="">All Locations</option>
            <option  name="location" value="Abids">Abids</option>
            <option  name="location" value="Ameerpet">Ameerpet</option>
            <option  name="location" value="Attapur">Attapur</option>
            <option  name="location" value="bandlaguda">Bandlaguda</option>
            <option  name="location" value="banjara hills">Banjara Hills</option>
            <option  name="location" value="basheerbagh">Basheerbagh</option>
            <option  name="location" value="begumpet">Begumpet</option>
            <option  name="location" value="bowenpally">Bowenpally</option>
            <option  name="location" value="chaitanyapuri">Chaitanyapuri</option>
            <option  name="location" value="chikkadapally">Chikkadapally</option>
            <option  name="location" value="dilsuknagar">Dilsuknagar</option>
            <option  name="location" value="gachibowli">Gachibowli</option>
            <option  name="location" value="himayath nagar">Himayath Nagar</option>
            <option  name="location" value="jubilee hills">Jubilee Hills</option>
            <option  name="location" value="karmanghat">Karmanghat</option>
            <option  name="location" value="kachiguda">Kachiguda</option>
            <option  name="location" value="kondapur">Kondapur</option>
            <option  name="location" value="kothapet">Kothapet</option>
             <option  name="location" value="koti">Koti</option>
            <option  name="location" value="KPHB">KPHB</option>
            <option  name="location" value="Kukatpally">Kukatpally</option>
            <option  name="location" value="LB Nagar">LB Nagar</option>
            <option  name="location" value="madhapur">Madhapur</option>
            <option  name="location" value="malkajgiri">Malkajgiri</option>
            <option  name="location" value="manikonda">Manikonda</option>
            <option  name="location" value="mansoorabad">Mansoorabad</option>
            <option  name="location" value="miyapur">Miyapur</option>
            <option  name="location" value="nagole">Nagole</option>
            <option  name="location" value="narayanaguda">Narayanaguda</option>
            <option  name="location" value="Ramnagar">Ram Nagar</option>
            <option  name="location" value="RTCXRoads">RTCxRoads</option>
            <option  name="location" value="saroornagar">Saroornagar</option>
            <option  name="location" value="secunderabad">Secunderabad</option>
            <option  name="location" value="santoshnagar">Santoshnagar</option>
            <option  name="location" value="srinagar colony">Srinagar colony</option>
            <option  name="location" value="tarnaka">Tarnaka</option>
            <option  name="location" value="Toli chowki">Toli Chowki</option>
            <option  name="location" value="Uppal">Uppal</option>
            <option  name="location" value="yusufguda">Yusufguda</option>!-->


       </select> 
        </div>

    <button type="submit"  title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>
    <!-- <button type="submit"  title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></button> -->
</form>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
function customSearch()
{
    var frm = document.getElementById ('form-custom-search');
    var name=frm.elements["name"];
var city=frm.elements["city"];
    var pincode=frm.elements["pincode"];
    var location=frm.elements["location"];

    if((pincode=='' && location=='') || (pincode=='Pincode' && location=='Location'))
    {
        alert('NORMAL search');
    }
    else
    {
        frm.action="<?php echo $this->getAdvanceSearchPostUrl() ?>";
        //frm.action="<?php echo $this->getNormalSearchPostUrl() ?>";
           frm.submit(); 
    }

   }
  //]]>
  </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.labwise.in/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css/jquery-ui.min.css" media="all" />



<script>
    /*
     * jQuery UI Autocomplete: Using Label-Value Pairs
     * http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html
     */
    var data = [{label: "ABO blood typing" },
    {label: "Acid Fast Bacilli (AFB) (Staining, Smear & culture sensitivity) - Sputum" },
    {label: "Activated Partial Thromboplastin Time (aPTT)" },
   {label: "AFP (Alpha Feto Protein)" },
   {label: "Albumin (Serum)" },
   {label: "Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP / ALKP)" },
   {label: "Amoebiasis" },
   {label: "Amylase (AMY)- serum" },
  {label: "Androstenedione (A4) - Serum" },
 {label: "Anti CCP (Antibody to Cyclic Citrullinated Peptide)" },
 {label: "Anti Chlamydia antibody (IgG / IgA)" },
 {label: "Anti Hepatitis C Virus (AHCV) - Total" },
 {label: "Anti Insulin Bodies" }
    ];
    $(function() {

        $("#name").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();
                // manually update the textbox
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();
                // manually update the textbox and hidden field
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                $('#ui-id-1').css('z-index','22222');
                //$("#autocomplete2-value").val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script>

 function autocompleteLocation(city){    



/*Please note that the URL is created in reloadurl. Also see that the    response text will be echoed in div with id=output-div*/
 var reloadurl = 'http://www.labwise.in/serviceprovider/index/autoLocation/';

new Ajax.Request(reloadurl, {
method: 'post',
 parameters: "city="+city,
 onComplete: function(transport) {
//alert(transport.responseText);
document.getElementById('location_div').innerHTML=transport.responseText;
}
});

}
```

Comment: can you provide link??

Comment: select the city Kodangulluru it is not showing the location

Comment: i think data was missing for that..